# How to display value in Timepicker while update existing data?

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

Actually, I want to update the timepicker value but ant design can't display defaultValue. How I can display my database time/value in timepicker ? I am using ant design framework.
[image]

Comment: Mentioned here: https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=001

Comment: And here https://ant.design/components/time-picker/

Answer (score 1):

There is no code in codepen. You can refer the code on Ant Design. I guess the variable departingTime is the cause.

```
    <TimePicker defaultValue={moment('12:08:23', 'HH:mm:ss')} />
```